# C++ for loop initializing counter wrong

Tags: c++

I have a simple for-loop in C++ and the initialization statement is:

> for (int n = 0; n < this->fileLines.size(); n++) {

For some crazy reason, the value of n is being set not to 0 but to 249758, which causes the for-loop to evaluate wrong.

Any ideas why this is initializing wrong (i.e., not to 0)?

[image]

Comment: Are you building in debug or release mode? oftain release mode cannot give you correct values when you peek at variable values due to optimization.

Comment: It looks like you've stopped just before `n` is initialised. What happens if you step forward by one instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to verify after the for loop what the value of n is, I don't see any way this could non-0.  Check the value at the start of the switch.  Your breakpoint may have interrupted before n was actually set.

Comment: Agreed.  The screenshot shows that the line `n = 0;` is about to execute, but hasn't yet.

Comment: the switch never executes... if you put a breakpoint in the switch, it is never triggered. The loop never occurs because n > size()

Comment: What is the value of this->fileLines.size()?

Comment: After a lot of playing around, what seems to have happened is as follows: (1) I was getting confused by the debugger. n seems to have been declared but not initialized and (2) it would never be initialized because as @jeremy pointed out correctly, the variable value was never greater than 0; The lesson: thoroughly unit test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sticking

```
std::cerr<<n<<std::endl;
```

inside of the `for` loop? This seems a more direct way of observing the value during the running of the program to verify whether or not it is doing what you think, and optimization will not give you problems with this output.

Perhaps your program is multithreaded and someone is inappropriately writing to that memory location?